# Excel 2003, VBA not deleting all OLE/shape controls

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a routine that deletes checkboxes and labels which are dynamically added to a sheet.  However, it doesn't realiably delete all the controls.  I need to ensure they are completely removed before adding again.

Here is my routine:

```
    Public Sub removeOLEtypesOfType()
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim intPass As Integer, objShape As Shape
        For intPass = 1 To 2
            For Each objShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                Dim strName As String
                strName = objShape.Name
                If Mid(strName, 1, Len(CHECKBOX_PREFIX)) = CHECKBOX_PREFIX _
                Or Mid(strName, 1, Len(LABEL_PREFIX)) = LABEL_PREFIX _
                Or Mid(strName, 1, 5) = "Label" Then
                    objShape.Delete
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

I only added the two pass for loop to ensure the objects are deleted, but even this doesn't delete the remaining items.  The issue I have is that I end up with controls that were not deleted in the workbook.

I'm only trying to delete checkboxes and labels where in the case of checkboxes the name is prefixed with:

```
    Public Const CHECKBOX_PREFIX As String = "chkbx"
```

Labels are prefixed with:

```
    Public Const LABEL_PREFIX As String = "lbl"
```

The 3rd search comparing with 'Label' is an attempt to mop up but even this doesn't catch all.

Is there any way to delete all shapes / ole objects within a range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I rewrote the sub-routine after a google search on how to delete shapes within a range:

```
    Public Sub removeOLEtypesOfType()
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim objTopLeft As Range, objBotRight As Range
        Dim objRange As Range, objShape As Shape
        Set objRange = Sheet1.Range(COLUMN_HEADINGS)
        With objRange
            Set objTopLeft = .Cells(1).Address(0, 0)
            Set objBotRight = .cell(.Cells.Count).Address(0, 0)

            For Each objShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                If Mid(objShape.Name, 1, Len(CHECKBOX_PREFIX)) = CHECKBOX_PREFIX _
                Or Mid(objShape.Name, 1, Len(LABEL_PREFIX)) = LABEL_PREFIX Then
                    If Not Intersect(objTopLeft, objShape.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing And _
                    Not Intersect(objBotRight, objShape.BottomRightCell) Is Nothing Then
                        objShape.Delete
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End Sub
```